# What does "dar" mean in this sentence?

Tags: translation, separable-verb

> Baerbock betonte, die Diplomaten stellten eine Bedrohung
> dar für Menschen, die in Deutschland Schutz suchten.

Baerbock emphasized, that the diplomats posed a threat ___ for people, that sought protection in Germany.

https://www.deutschlandfunk.de/deutschland-weist-zahlreiche-russische-diplomaten-aus-100.html

Google Translate and DeepL and Wiktionary don't clear this up for me. Is this a typo?

Comment: The link in RHa's comment should answer the question, but I thought some additional explanation would be helpful. Unlike most separable prefixes, *dar* does not have a meaning of its own (at least in Modern German). So if you ever see it then it's safe to assume that it belongs to a finite verb earlier in the sentence. It's unusual for it not to be the last "word" in a clause, but I think that can be explained by the following noun being referred to in the next clause. The verb *darstellen* usually translates as "to represent", which fits the context here.